# Prevent list item padding from wrapping in a horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal unordered list `<ul>` with four columns in each row.
The number of list items `<li>` is dynamic and could change during runtime.

**Current Code and result**

```
ul {
  -webkit-columns: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 4; /* Firefox */
  columns: 4;
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  margin: 20px ;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: list-item;
}
```

which gives me this:
[image]

The list is  not really horizontal since the second element (Green) is under the first one (Blue) and next to it, but the order doesn't matter in my case.

The problem is that the **padding** of the element is wrapping to the next column.

Any suggestions?

JSfiddle:   [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zb7znwab/)

Comment: Would be great to get jsfiddle with html in it.

Comment: @Paran0a, there it is

Comment: Why are you using `columns` in the first place, support is horrible http://caniuse.com/#search=column ?

Comment: @Paran0a, you might need to run again

Comment: It doesn't look that way in your example picture.

Comment: @NenadVracar, any other alternatives?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/zb7znwab/12/

Comment: @NenadVracar, please post this as an answer, 
is there anyway to do it without the js ?

Comment: Maybe there is but i am not sure.

Comment: Checkout my updated aswnser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa722/880/)**

```
<ul id = "list">
 <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">1</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">2</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(121, 159, 59);">3</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">4</li>    
 <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">5</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(121, 159, 59);">6</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">7</li>
 <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">8</li>
</ul>

 #list {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
       -moz-column-count: 4;
            column-count: 4; /*3 is just placeholder -- can be anything*/
}
#list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
        padding:10px 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but is the same result as the previous answer, Three columns, and not four.

Comment: four columns in each row

Comment: The problem is I can't add a span element, the HTML is generated from the server

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [break-inside](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-inside) property.

```css
    ul {
     -webkit-columns: 4;
     /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-columns: 4;
     /* Firefox */
     columns: 4;
     display: block;
     list-style: none;
      

   }
   
  ul li {
     margin: 20px;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     min-height: 50px;
     display: list-element;
     -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid; 
     -moz-column-break-inside:avoid; 
     -o-column-break-inside:avoid; 
     -ms-column-break-inside:avoid; 
      column-break-inside:avoid;
   }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">1</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(121, 159, 59);">2</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(133, 50, 104);">3</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(75, 93, 135);">4</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(151, 187, 93);">5</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great!, but it is generating three columns instead of four. anyway around it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is other alternative to your approach using **JS** and **Flexbox**. First you group each 4 `li` elements with `wrapper` element and then you use flexbox to create 4 column layout.

```js
$('ul').each(function(){
    var divs = $('li', this);
    console.log(divs)
    console.log(divs.slice(0,4));
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
        console.log(i)
        divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<li class="wrapper"><ul></ul></li>');
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
   
.wrapper ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper ul li  {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">1</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(121, 159, 59);">2</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(133, 50, 104);">3</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(75, 93, 135);">4</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(151, 187, 93);">5</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">6</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(75, 93, 135);">4</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(151, 187, 93);">5</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">6</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 70, 115);">1</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(121, 159, 59);">2</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(133, 50, 104);">3</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(75, 93, 135);">4</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(151, 187, 93);">5</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(156, 78, 129);">6</li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(75, 93, 135);">4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The solution is great, but I can't change the HTML structure, it has to be parsed later.
Thank you so much though

Answer (score 0):

You can add `min-height` to that `<li>` , it may solved your problem :-

```
ul li
{
      margin: 20px ;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      min-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: i think i made small mistake in it.

Comment: This solution won't work, it will just make both items in the column bigger. it won't push an item to the next column